# What's the difference between "endlich" and "schließlich"?

Tags: difference

I have up till now used both *endlich* and *schließlich* to mean "finally" but I'm suspicious there is a subtle difference in meaning.

Can anyone please clarify?

For example if I want to say:

> I have finally won the gold medal I've been trying so hard to win.

or

> The movie is finally over.

Is there any difference?

Comment: When in doubt, use "schlußendlich" :)

Comment: @Ingo, ausgerechnet in diesem Wort ein **ß** zu benutzen, erscheint mir fragwürdig.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Jetzt, wo du es sagst ... in der Tat! Ist halt eingedeutscht :)

Comment: the answers are quite good, so I'll just add here what I think might help... "endlich" is somewhat close to "at long last, at length"."Schließlich" is more like "and finally" or "ultimately".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Schließlich**

Is used to denote the (perceived or planned) ending of a (long) process.

> Schließlich kam Sam wieder im Auenland an.

**Endlich**

Is used to denote the occurence of a (long) awaited event. There is no information about repetitions or the ongoingness afterwards.

> Endlich hat Sam Rosie zum Tanzen aufgefordert.

**Your examples**

> I have finally won the gold medal I've been trying so hard to win.

Both translations are possible, depending on what you want to express.

- If you want to express, that after maybe several failed attempts, you managed to win your first gold medal (of this kind) you should use `endlich`. Maybe your career continued and you won several more gold medals.
- If you want to express, that a long career or hard season concludes with the winning of this gold medal, you should use `schließlich`. Your career or at least the season are finished afterwards.

> The movie is finally over.

Again, both translations are possible:

- If you want to express, that you have waited for the ending (maybe because it was such a bad or boring movie), you should use `endlich`.
- If you want to express, that being over is an essential part of the movie, you should use `schließlich`. Think of a narrator in a parody, who doesn't narrate a story but the movie itself.

Comment: +1 for LotR reference :)

Answer (score 10):

There is a notable difference. In both your examples, I would use "endlich". You use "endlich" when you couldn't wait for something. The emphasis is on the fact that you had to wait too long for it.

> Endlich ist Wochenende!
>
> Es klingelt. Das muss Thomas sein. Na endlich!

The word "schließlich" can be used if you describe an event when the emphasis is on the completion of some process and the outcome was not predictable. Yet, "endlich" can still be used in place of it.

> Ich habe lange überlegt, welches Auto ich mir kaufe. Schließlich/Endlich entschied ich mich für XYZ.

In the preceding sentence, "schließlich" is IMHO better, because the duration of the decision process was determined only by yourself, and there was no waiting. But in your example with the gold medal, "endlich" seems better, because external factors influenced the long waiting time.

Note that both words have further meanings that have nothing to do with what we have told about: "endlich" can mean "finite" like in:

> Die Menge der geraden Primzahlen ist endlich.

and "schließlich" can mean something like "after all":

> Wir könnten mal ausschlafen. Schließlich ist Wochenende.

Comment: Der (klischeehaft männliche) Autokäufer würde wohl kaum sagen: `Endlich entschied ich mich für XYZ.` Es wäre wohl eher dessen (klischeehafte) Ehefrau, die eigenlich schon lange das Mittagessen fertig haben wollte und die ganze gewartet hat, bis Ehemann sich endlich entschieden hat.

Comment: Keinen Sexismus hier, bitte @Toscho ;-)

Comment: Deswegen ja auch der Hinweis aufs Klischee.

Answer (score 7):

You will use "endlich" if impatience plays a role. If impatience doesn't play a role, you will just use "schließlich".

Example: You have waited a long time for your brother Jack to visit you, then you can say:

> Endlich bist Du gekommen!

You can also say "Na endlich!". There is NO "Na schließlich!"

"Schließlich" is a short form of "...zu dem Schluss gekommen...", something that is a conclusion and mustn't - as said before - have to do something with impatience. "Auf etwas schließen" or "Zu dem Schluß kommen" e. g. "schließlich" is a consequence of something that is logically true compared to the subject.

Comment: shouldn't it be needn't (= muss nicht) instead of mustn't (= darf nicht)? I'm not editing, because that would change the meaning, but I suspect that is what you would mean.

Comment: with mustn't i meant "must not". i bet need not or needn't is ok as well.

Answer (score 0):

"Schließlich" refers to the **closing** of an event. Schließen: to close (or finish).

"Endlich" refers to an **endpoint** (in time). It has the connotation of "finally."

Answer (score 0):

- Endlich ist der Winter vorbei. 
  Hier deutet man an, der Winter war lang, aber, Gott sei dank, ist er jetzt zu Ende.
  "schließlich" würde hier nicht passen.

Answer (score -1):

"schließlich" I would use it to show an resulting or following event. First he did clean the dishes, "schließlich" finally (following) he went to the bathroom to brush his teeth. OR: He finished cleaning the dishes, "schließlich" finally (as a result) he could go to the bathroom.
"Endlich" you use to show your gratitude something finally happend: "Endlich ging er ins Bad um sich die Zähne zu putzen!" Finally he went to the bathroom to brush his teeth! OR: Finally I did won my gold medal! "Endlich habe ich meine Gold-Medaille gewonnen!"
Both means finally. You could use "schließlich" also in the context of winning the gold medal. But it would have indeed a different meaning. I trained so hard and tried so many times, that I finally (as a consequence) won a gold medal. = "Ich habe so hart trainiert und es so oft versucht (eine Gold-Medaille zu gewinnen), (so dass ich schließlich eine Gold-Medaille gewonnen habe) schließlich habe ich eine Gold-Medaille gewonnen." (BUT: "endlich" in the place of "schließlich" would be correct too, only difference is you would explain your gratitude)
Talking about the movie: Using "endlich" means you waited for (and appreciate) the movie to end: "Endlich ist der Film zu Ende!" Finally the movie ends! (Thank god!) "Schließlich" would be used to show that as a consequence the movie finally ended. "Der Prinz tötete den Räuber, heiratete die Prinzessin und schließlich war der Film zu Ende." OR: "Sie schauten den ganzen Abend Fernsehen bis schließlich der letzte Film zu Ende war und die Dauerwerbesendungen begannen."
But "endlich" means also something got an end! "Das Leben ist endlich!" = Live is finite! "Schönheit ist endlich." "Jugend ist endlich." and so on. You cannot use "schließlich" in this context. "Das Leben ist schließlich" is totally wrong. But you can write: "Schließlich war sein Leben zu Ende." Finally his life ended. (as a consequence, result, following something that happend before. I.e. many years of joyfull live or a long suffering from sickness..)
"Endlich war sein Leben zu Ende!" means you hoped for, waited for, appreciate his life to end. Maybe to stop his suffering, maybe to inherit the money, maybe because you wished him his death.
Hope I could help. My references? None, I am just german and I read some books in the past, so maybe I told you something wrong... :-) Cheers!!

Comment: Make paragraphs! Your posting is unreadable!