# Are "Ende" and "Schluss" synonyms?

Tags: word-usage, difference, synonym

is there any difference between "das Ende" and "der Schluss" in meaning? Can it be used interchangeably as synonyms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "endlich" and "schließlich"?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9864/whats-the-difference-between-endlich-and-schlie%c3%9flich)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They can be used as synonyms in some contexts, but they also have some very different meanings.

"Schluss" can mean the *conclusion* of some action or argument. "Ende" can not be used in that context. Although you could say:

> Am Ende kam ich zu dem Schluss, dass ...

Conversely, "Ende" often refers to the end of some physical things. "Schluss" generally can't do that:

> Am Ende der Straße machte er Schluss.

Generally, "Ende" refers to the end of some physical object or process, but "Schluss" refers to the conclusion of some process, argument, thought, performance etc.
Have a saying illustrating the ambiguity of "Ende":

> Alles hat ein Ende, nur die Wurst hat zwei.

Answer (score 5):

`Am Ende` or `zum Schluss` may be a bit like a synonym in several cases where they are used in an action context.

```
Am Ende der Handlung.  
Zum Schluss der Handlung
```

But `Ende` is also used for termination points like `Am Ende der Straße`. Im that case you can't use `Schluss`.

`Schluss` is also used as `Es lässt den Schluss zu` where you can't use `Ende`.

So, `Ende` and `Schluss` may look like synonyms, but there are not interchangeable in general.

Comment: Removed the upvote to disapprove of excessive code markup usage

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are synonyms, but they are used differently in certain idioms, for example:

- it's always "das dicke Ende", but never "der dicke Schluss"
- to end an informal love relationship (not a marriage), you can say "mit jemandem Schluss machen"
- "Schluss damit!" means "stop that!", and again, "Ende damit" would not fit
- "von Anfang bis Ende" --- from start to finish ("Anfang bis Schluss" würde man nicht sagen)
- "am Ende des Films"

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to @Robert's answer, **Schluss** has different meanings.

- **Schluss** in the meaning of end which is discussed in another answer
- **Schluss** as derivation of some statement, eg

  - **Er kam zu dem Schluss, dass es sinnlos ist.**
- **Schluss** has also a meaning in electronics, eg

  - **Kurzschluss** is **short circuit**
- **Schluss** is also the noun to **schließen**, but this is mostly obsolete.

Answer (score -6):

Ende means something like ending, BUT Schluss means having your pubic hair removed in a very weird fashion.

Comment: I've never heard ``Schluss`` with that meaning. Could you please cite any sources for that...